# Get id of element in another View with jQuery or AngularJS

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, angularjs

I have a MVC project. In this project I have multiple Views. In one of my View I have a button and in a other View I have a div.

When I click on the button I want the div be disabled. But how do I get the div element from the other View? Here below a little example:

Index.cshtml:

```
<div id="firstDiv">Hello</div>
```

SecondView.cshtml:

```
<button class="btn" onclick="DisableFirstDiv()">Disable div</button>
<script>
    function DisableFirstDiv() {
        //What to do? How do I get the div element from the other View?
    }
</script>
```

Comment: http is stateless protocol. so you have to figure out how to preserve state while a user is navigating your site. Generally you can use query string or cookies for this.

Answer (score 0):

If they are inside of the same page:

```
 function DisableFirstDiv() {
     $("#firstDiv") //Do your magic
}
```

But, if you they are not inside of the same page and you wanna use AngularJS. You can store a flag or information inside of the service.